# How can I make my sliding animation begin at the edge of the page?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I have an SVG image that I animated sliding from the left into the frame.

The problem is, the animation begins at the left edge of the object, and not the left edge of the page.

How can I make the animation begin at the edge of the page?

When I add margin or padding on the object, it just starts the animation further from the edge of the page.

When I add margin or padding inside the SVG, it accomplishes the goal but cuts off the SVG on the right.

HTML Body:

```
<body style="background:#3F6184;">
  <div class="full-w">
  <object class="hi" data="static/images/Hi.svg"></object>
 </div>
</body>
```

svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="hi" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 160.562 148.92" style="enable-background:new 0 0 160.562 148.92;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st1{font-family:'MyriadPro-It';}
    .st2{font-size:137px;}
    .st3{letter-spacing:4;}
    #hi {
    -webkit-animation: slide-in-blurred-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) both;
            animation: slide-in-blurred-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) both;
}
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-in-blurred-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px) scaleX(2.5) scaleY(0.2);
            transform: translateX(-1000px) scaleX(2.5) scaleY(0.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
            transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(40px);
            filter: blur(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
            transform: translateX(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
            filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-in-blurred-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px) scaleX(2.5) scaleY(0.2);
            transform: translateX(-1000px) scaleX(2.5) scaleY(0.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
            transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(40px);
            filter: blur(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
            transform: translateX(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
            filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

</style>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 114.6699)" class="st0 st1 st2">Hi,</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a stylesheet to the HTML document containing `body { margin: unset; }` or `* { all: unset; }` to remove the default page margins.